# ActiveRecord update produce an infinite SQL transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Is there any way that this code:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  if @branch.update(branch_params) # <---- HERE is the update!
    #...
  else
    #...
  end
end
```

...could produce the following infinite SQL transaction?

```
May 24 17:22:43 myapp app/web.1:  Processing by BranchesController#update as HTML 
May 24 17:22:43 myapp app/web.1:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXX", "branch"=>{"google_page"=>"https://plus.google.com", "fanpage_oauth_token"=>"XXX"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"55"} 
May 24 17:22:44 myapp app/web.1:     (1.1ms)  BEGIN 
May 24 17:22:44 myapp app/web.1:    SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "branches" SET "fanpage_oauth_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "branches"."id" = $3  [["fanpage_oauth_token", "XXX"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-24 21:22:43.654824"], ["id", 55]] 
May 24 17:22:44 myapp app/web.1:    SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE "branches" SET "fanpage_oauth_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "branches"."id" = $3  [["fanpage_oauth_token", "XXX"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-24 21:22:43.654824"], ["id", 55]] 
May 24 17:22:44 myapp app/web.1:    SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE "branches" SET "fanpage_oauth_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "branches"."id" = $3  [["fanpage_oauth_token", "XXX"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-24 21:22:43.654824"], ["id", 55]] 
May 24 17:22:44 myapp app/web.1:    SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "branches" SET "fanpage_oauth_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "branches"."id" = $3  [["fanpage_oauth_token", "XXX"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-24 21:22:43.654824"], ["id", 55]] 
May 24 17:22:44 myapp app/web.1:    SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "branches" SET "fanpage_oauth_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "branches"."id" = $3  [["fanpage_oauth_token", "XXX"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-24 21:22:43.654824"], ["id", 55]] 
May 24 17:22:44 myapp app/web.1:    SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "branches" SET "fanpage_oauth_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "branches"."id" = $3  [["fanpage_oauth_token", "XXX"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-24 21:22:43.654824"], ["id", 55]] 
... and so on for +100 times until Heroku's timeout
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at any activerecord hooks you've defined on your underlying Branch model. I've never seen this, but I think it could be that you have an update that triggers its own update via hooks...

Comment: This can also happen if you have this occurring within a `rescue` block, where something else is causing an error, and you don't have an exit condition for the `rescue` block (e.g. maximum retry count).